# hostgator - change python version

Tags: python

I opened a ticket with hostgator but trying to fix this on my own.

On my shared hostgator account, when I do python -V. It gives me 2.6.6
I need to use 2.7 which they do have, but doesn't work on my shebang line.

1)So, how do I change my python command to point to 2.7
I tried modifying the .bash_profile but the 2.7 path is added at the end.

2)Actually my shebang line needs to work as well.

Comment: Run `python2.7` instead of `python2` or `python`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the below comment for the same problem posted by someone else on Google Groups. I am also experiencing the same problem, but haven't yet tried the below mentioned approach yet. Please try if you find it might help.

[Google Groups link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/DVvnqb7iVVI)

---

Hi, I'm also using hostgator to host a django project.

first of all note that they have different plans with different features, what I'm going to write applies to their shared hosting plans.

Looks like they are using some version of centos, which comes with python 2.6 I believe.

Installing a python from source on your home folder is a good idea, but unfortunately hostgator blocks access to gcc.

on the other hand they already have python 2.7.3 installed, juts use python2.7 as the executable, try running "python2.7 -V"

btw, they also have python2.6 for 2.6.6 and python3 for 3.2.3

after that you should use virtualenv to create a project specific env so you can install things using pip. download the virtualenv.py file to you project folder and run it from there. for the index.fcgi file you should put this in the first line:

```
#!/home/username/projectname/env/bin/python
```

other than that I think it should be standard

Comment: You could wish to edit your answer [in Markdown format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to mark the shebang line as code, and not as an heading.